# How to find time intervals corresponding to specific value of time series data in python?

Tags: python, time-series, grouping

In a time series, How can I find the intervals of maximum value. For example in one day data, I have maximum interval from 10:00 to 10:40 and then other interval from 19:00 to 19:20. By using the idxmax() function, I am able to find the starting time but not ending time. Also, I cann't find any other intervals in this way.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Siva Shanmugam: I have done by comparing values but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Update your code with error.

Comment: @Siva Shanmugam: Thanks for your reply. I have a panda series power and I am able to find all index corresponding to the maximum value through the following code:
power[power==power.max()].index
now, I am stuck how to determine the intervals out of it

Comment: Glad that you solved it on your own.